# What is the best practice for a multi-tenant app with Collection Group Queries in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best practice for multi-tenant app collection group queries? For example query all invoices for a tenant's customers

```
/tenant/1/customer/2/invoices
```

If I create a collection group index called **invoices**, and I want to ensure that I can get all **invoices** for tenant 1, how do I do this easily?

I tried setting up some security rules to prevent from querying over the tenants but it still threw Access denied errors since it was still querying across tenants. What would the correct firestore rules look like

Comment: There is an accepted answer but based on your comments, some additional data is needed before continuing. While you can create multi projects per @DougStevenson suggestion, 5 or 10 may be manageable but 500 will get out of control. For example, Firebase rules are *per project*. If you add a new field to a document, that may need to be secured by *Rules*. You'll then have to update the *Rules* on 500 *different projects*. I don't know your codebase but you will also have to have 500 different plists, 500 different sets of authentication etc. In other words, think through it *carefully*.

Comment: @Jay I am not worried about the rules because they are consistent between projects but am more concerned about deploying and keeping all up to date via ci

Comment: Understood. Just imagine though, making a minor tweak to a rule then having to repeat that action 500 times: Firebase console, select the first project->Rules, paste the changes, save. Select project 2->Rules, paste the changes, save. Rinse, repeat 500 times - every time a change is made. Then consider having 500 totally different sets of authentication and 500 differently named apps. I am a Firebase advocate by the way but wanted to make sure you had all of the data. I didn't have that leg up to start with and spent a year in development just to have to change platforms.

Comment: @Jay but could this not be solved via some ci process that is automated ?

Comment: I believe Rules can be deployed via the Firebase Command Line Interface but that adds another layer to the project. Although I think it's missing some functionality like rollbacks and I don't think there's direct versioning control. Again though - just be aware of the additional complexity and resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase projects are not very well suited to multi-tenant apps.  It's recommended that you create different projects for each tenant.  **This will save you a lot of problems in the future.**

If you absolutely must have multi-tenancy on a single project, your current database structure does not support it very well for collection group queries.  Collection group queries **always** query every collection of a given name, with no exceptions.  You can't use security rules to filter the results, because [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  Filtering can only come from the client, and be confirmed by security rules.  With your current structure, you would need to store the ID of the tenant in each document that you intend to query with a collection group query, and have the client use that as a filter for results.

Comment: Our app has a decent amount of tenants, 500 or so wouldn't this get dramatically more expensive.

Comment: Why would it? If anything, the costs would go down, since there is a free billing allowance to each individual project.

Comment: is there any limit or cap of the number of projects?

Comment: Yes, but it's not static, and it only applies to projects on the Spark (free) plan.  There are no limits to the number of projects on a payment plan.  You should contact Firebase support if you have questions or concerns about that.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Thanks so much Doug! Keep up the good work, you just shook up my world on this project but probably for the better.

Comment: Kind of unrelated, but is there a good way to contact the firebase dev advocates? I had a copy of something I wanted to put in their hands.

Comment: Please go through Firebase support for all requests using the link I gave previously.

Comment: It's been a few years but any chance you could elaborate on what those lots of problems could be, @DougStevenson? If I added `tenantId` to every document I store, would that address most of them?

Comment: Multi-tenancy in auth with identity platform has also developed further since this question was answered.
Is the recommendation still to split across project?